# Data of Coronal Holes

Tags: observational-astronomy, the-sun, data-analysis, solar-wind, corona

I'm working on the **Evolution of coronal holes** for which I need data of Coronal Holes, I have searched on internet and also done literature survey but didn't find out any open-source catalogue where I can download the data for Coronal Holes, In certain papers mentioned below

- [A statistical study of long–term evolution of coronal hole
  properties as observed by SDO](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.02795.pdf)
- [Statistical Analysis and Catalog of Non-polar Coronal Holes Covering
  the SDO-Era Using CATCH](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11207-019-1539-y)

Some people have taken the data from Satellite (Solar Dynamic Observatory) and some have used the **CATCH** Software (It's user manual is not opening so can't download the **CATCH**-*Collection of Analysis Tools for Coronal Holes* software.

> - My question is that is there anyone out there who is working on Solar    parameters such as Coronal Holes and can provide me the data
>   of coronal holes from 21st    Solar cycle up to 25th Solar Cycle.

.

Comment: Your question seems to imply that the Solar Dynamic Observatory (SDO) is a ground based observatory - this is not the case, it's a satellite in geosynchronous orbit. As coronal holes are best observed in EUV wavelength, it is not possible to do so from the surface of the Earth.

Comment: What data do you want to have? It seems to me that your best bet would be to email the authors of the paper and ask if they are willing to share a table of the summarized data you seek.

Comment: I want to have a data of Coronal Holes Parameters through which I can study about the structure of Coronal Hole.